# .slidetoggle() toggles once too often after .click() event

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, scrolltop

This is what I am trying to do for my site (not yet live or I would post a link): I want a div to to be hidden when the page first loads (scrolltop() ==0) and to slideup or slidetoggle when the user scrolls down. This works so far.  But I would also like the page itself to scroll to the top and for the div to simultaneously slidedown right after clicking it. The problem: once it disappears, and the page is scrolling up, the initial if-else is triggered and the div slides up and down an extra time.  How can I resolve it so that it just stays hidden after the user clicks, but reappears when he/she decides to scroll down again?  As an side: The footer is a sticky footer, too (I don't know if this is necessary but it keeps it at the bottom of the page). Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
    if($("#footer").length>0)
    $("#footer").hide();});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $("#footer:visible").slideToggle('fast',"swing",function(){});
    }
else {
    $("#footer:hidden").slideToggle('fast',"swing",function(){});
}});


$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.fill-div').click(function(){
    $('#footer').slideToggle('fast',"swing",function(){});
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    $("#footer").die('slideToggle');
    return false;
});
});
```

I have only been coding a couple of months so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Couldn't get the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/5HfNb/6/) to work properly to demonstrate, but this will help illustrate the positioning.

Edit: I found out that my slideToggle() code above was not playing nicely with Masonry since, when adding new jQuery functionality for IE7 browser error message handling within script tags offset the Masonry, and the slideToggle() code above worked as intended. However, the link that Harsh posted in the accepted answer works with the Masonry and fixes my problem the right way, pr0-m0de.

Comment: @Harsh Baid, you seriously edited my post with taking out my "Thank you" at the end? If you don't know the answer and have nothing even moderately constructive to contribute, leave it alone, move on, and see if you can help someone else. "Thank you".

Comment: Hi, I would love to help you but at the point of editing your question I was [reviewing](http://stackoverflow.com/review/) the questions not answering.. for more details about why I removed 'Thanks' check [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/168386)

Comment: Are you trying to create an always visible pane which is on its place initially and as user scrolls down it turns into absolute and sticks with the user at certain position ? secondly pls post a sample html or image as it is not clear to me what is to be done from description..

Comment: Very efficient and reasonable linked discussion and it is appreciated. I will abstain from formalities in all future posts. I will edit this current comment with a jFiddle once I get to my personal computer where the code resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to check and fix the problem that I understood please check the [live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AHgSW/)

Changes I have made in your versions:

1. Changed `slideToggle` to `slideUp` and `slideDown` in `window scroll` event to hide and show respectively.

**Code as shown below**

*HTML*

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#test" class="fill-div">
        Testing Anchor
    </a>
    <div>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <a href="#test" class="fill-div">
        Testing Anchor
    </a>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer content Footer content Footer content Footer content Footer content Footer content
</div>
```

---

*JavaScript*

```
$(function() {
    if($("#footer").length>0)
    $("#footer").hide();
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $("#footer:visible").slideUp('fast',function(){});
    }
    else {
      $("#footer:hidden").slideDown('fast',function(){});
}});


$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a.fill-div').click(function(){
    $('#footer').slideToggle('fast',function(){});
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    $("#footer").die('slideToggle');
    return false;
 });
});
```

I hope it will work for you.

### UPDATE

After looking at your [jsfildle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/5HfNb/21/), I can understand that you want scrollToTop kind of jquery implementation which is already developed by [many](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?q=jquery%20scroll%20to%20top%20plugin) you can check one [here](http://markgoodyear.com/labs/scrollup/) and [here](http://markgoodyear.com/2013/01/scrollup-jquery-plugin/). And use the plugins as it is or may be modify your implementation taking these as references. :D

Comment: Just ran it and even though it's not what I want, it still has the same problem if you observe the scrollbar. It 'toggle' back and forth after hitting the link in the sliding div before hiding again. Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/5HfNb/21/). It won't animate properly, but the #footer should slide up when you scroll down even just 1px into the window, stay at the bottom of the window at a fixed position while you keep scrolling. It slides back down out of the window view when you either scroll back up to top=0 with the mouse/scrollbar or when you click on the #footer.